# How to run prefect agent in background in centos

Tags: curl, prefect

I want to run prefect agent as background process.

```
prefect agent local start
```

also need to check the status of the running agent (health check)
for health check up i used below command

```
prefect agent local start -f --agent-address http://100.64.114.291:8081
```

but output of this command is always blank

```
curl --fail --silent "http://100.64.114.291/api/health"
```

Please help me .

Comment: Do you expect any output from using the `--silent` option?

Answer (score 0):

nohup command >/dev/null 2>&1 & # runs in background, still doesn't create nohup.out

replace command with 'prefect agent local start -f --agent-address [http://100.64.114.291:8081'](http://100.64.114.291:8081%27)